# Lightweight expressions parser in Java 1.6

Tags: java, expression, janino

I am looking for a lightweight lib which is able to parse and evaluate trivial conditions on java objects in order to implement string filters on objects

Example : 
Interpreting a string like :
`myObject.intField > 0 && myObject.booleanField` with myObject as param.

Some thing like Janino :
http://docs.codehaus.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/17273
But more Bean oriented (no need to use getters)

Could code my own parser but prefer avoid reimplementing the wheel.

Comment: Java has a built-in scripting API since Java 6, see the API docs of the package `javax.script`. There's built-in support for JavaScript but it can be extended with other scripting languages.

Comment: Have a look at EL (the Expression Language) there are several implementations - e.g. [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: what about lambdas in Java 8?

Comment: javax.script needs a ScriptEngine but default engines can be different among platforms (JVM version or OS Windows, *ix, OSX), so I will need to add a dependency to an engine like Rhino for JS, Groovy or anything else. I don't need a full-featured library but a simple expression parser and evaluator.

Comment: Or maybe I' m wrong. Is "Javascript" always provided as a ScriptEngine by default whatever the OS and the Java version (1.6+) ?

Answer (score 0):

Java (at least JavaEE 6) has an [Expression Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) built-in.

Comment: Really interesting to use EL but for now I didn't find the way to execute it from my Java code (no JSP, no JSF).